# How Can I Turn This Javascript Code Into Phaser Code?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

```
if(mouse.x && mouse.y) {
  myGameBall.x = mouse.x;
  myGameBall.y = mouse.y;
}
```

How can i turn this Javascript code into Phaser code?

Comment: ' window.addEventListener("mousemove" , function(e) {
                                    mouse.x = e.pageX;
                                    mouse.y = e.pageY;
                                    }); '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `game.input`, something like this

```
create = function() {
    // ..
    this.game.input.addMoveCallback(this.doMyGameMouseMove, this);
}

doMyGameMouseMove = function(evt) {
    if (evt.isDown) {
        myGameBall.x = evt.x;
        myGameBall.y = evt.y;
    }
}
```